# macbook can't recognize linux partition at startup

Tags: linux, mac, installation, macbook, boot

I'm using an Intel-based macbook,
I made a new partition with BootCamp, after that I inserted debian installation CD, deleted the FAT32 partition that was made by BootCamp, made 3 new partitions:
/ ex3 
/home ex3
and a swap partition,

after installing debian, I restarted macbook, but it couldn't recognize linux partitions,
in Mac OSx I can't find any of these partitions as startup disks, and I can't mount them in Disk Utility, 
How can I access these partitions? how can I boot to debian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to access your linux partitions from Disk Utility, but for booting i would definitely recommend [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/). It shows a boot menu at startup, and (if everything is set up right) lets you boot into Debian.

Comment: well, I tried rEFIt, and it only shows me the macOSx and rEFIt menu& tools, albeit, the linux partitions are listed in MBR partition list... but I still can't boot into debian...:(

Comment: Have you tried syncing the partition tables in rEFIt?

Comment: yup. after syncing it still doesn't recognize the partition, by the way, my linux partition is on the same HD as my macOSX, is that the problem?

Comment: No, I've had Ubuntu and OSX on the same HD working fine. Are you sure you installed GRUB in the right place?

Comment: hmm.. I'm not sure, how can check it now?

Comment: You could try to recover/reinstall GRUB; if that works, then it was probably the problem in the first place;-) Here's a guide: http://wiki.debian.org/GrubRecover

Comment: Great! Have fun

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X doesn't recognize ext2/ext3 partitions.

You can use a [MacFUSE](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) plugin like [fuse-ext2](http://alperakcan.org/?open=projects&project=fuse-ext2) to mount them in the Finder and make them available to the whole system.

If you only want to boot on one of these partitions, hold <kbd>alt</kbd> while booting your computer to select the boot disk (you don't need FUSE plugins to do this).

Comment: I tried the alt key, but it only shows me the Macintosh HD.

Comment: That's why you might want to look into rEFIt

Answer (score 1):

you could try holding the 'option' button when your computer boots. This will allow you to select the drive to boot from.

for more info, or some other interesting boot related keys, look [here](http://www.fif3.com/howto/archives/001983.html)

hope this helps